# How to find the root table for child table?

Tags: oracle

How to find the Root table for child tables ?

For example : -

```
 I have 26 tables A,B,C ...Z. I need to find the indirect relation for particular table

 B has relation with  A
 C has relation with B

 If i will give the table_name like c, it will come to A(indirect relation)
```

Comment: I dont think you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and use an hierarchical query on `user_constraints`

`PK` is `constraint_type = 'P'`

`FK` is `constraint_type = 'R'` and is linked to the primary key by `r_constraint_name`

Something along this lines might work  ( not tested )

```
select  table_name 
from    user_constraints 
start with 
    table_name = 'x' 
    and constraint_type = 'P' 
connect by r_constraint_name = prior constraint_name 
    and prior constraint_type = 'R'
```